# Using caret with recipes is leading to difficulties with resample

Tags: r, r-caret, r-recipes

I've been using recipes to pipe into `caret::train`, which has been going well, but now I've tried some step_transforms, I'm getting the error:

```
Error in resamples.default(model_list) : 
  There are different numbers of resamples in each model
```

when I compare models with and without the transformations. The same code with `step_centre` and `step_scale` works fine.

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

formula <- price ~ carat

model_recipe <- recipe(formula, data = diamonds)

quadratic_model_recipe <- recipe(formula, data = diamonds) %>% 
  step_poly(all_predictors())

model_list <- list(
  linear_model = NULL,
  quadratic  = NULL
)

model_list$linear_model <-
  model_recipe %>% train(
    data = diamonds,
    method = "lm",
    trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

model_list$quadratic_model <-
  quadratic_model_recipe %>% train(
    data = diamonds,
    method = "lm",
    trControl = trainControl(method = "cv"))

resamp <- resamples(model_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

quadratic  = NULL should have been quadratic_model  = NULL